# How do I pass an array as parameter from a View to an MVC controller through an ajax call?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that accepts an array and returns the View it is supposed to if I use the following Html.ActionLink:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Advanced Search Test", "ReqsSummary",routeValues: new{ReqDepartment= "Facilities",EquipmentGroup="Vehicles",SiteCode="LUR"})
```

I am eventually going to have about 20 parameters in the array. I have tried configuring the  ajax call a bunch of different ways but the values in the data array I pass never get to the controller. I'm using an MVVM pattern on the View. Here is the function in the viewModel I am trying to make work. The data array is being populated correctly before the ajax call, that's not the issue:

```
 submit: function () {
        var data = {
            "ReqDepartment": (viewModel.reqDepartment === null) ? null : viewModel.reqDepartment,
            "EquipmentGroup": (viewModel.equipmentGroup === null) ? null : viewModel.equipmentGroup,
            "SiteCode": (viewModel.site === null) ? null : viewModel.site.SiteCode,
        }; //header

        var criteria = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ArctecLogisticsWebApp/Requisitions/ReqsSummary/?",
                data: criteria,
                traditional: true

         });
```

The Controller:

```
public ViewResult ReqsSummary(ReqSearchCriteria criteria)
    {
        return View("ReqsSummary", requisitionsRepository.GetReqsAdvancedSearch(criteria));
        //This works when I use the  Html.ActionLink shown above. 
    }
```

And the ViewModel  ReqSearchCriteria:

```
 public class ReqSearchCriteria
{
    public string ReqDepartment { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentGroup { get; set; }
    public string SiteCode { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to stringify the data object, the default Model Binder will handle JSON object binding without the need for stringification.

```
submit: function () {
    var data = {
        "ReqDepartment": (viewModel.reqDepartment === null) ? null : viewModel.reqDepartment,
        "EquipmentGroup": (viewModel.equipmentGroup === null) ? null : viewModel.equipmentGroup,
        "SiteCode": (viewModel.site === null) ? null : viewModel.site.SiteCode,
    }; //header

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ArctecLogisticsWebApp/Requisitions/ReqsSummary/",
            data: data,
            traditional: true

     });
}
```